# Delete files older than 30 days, but in 1 directory the retention 6 months

Tags: linux, bash, scripting, find

I'd like to create a find which delete a files older than 30 days, but I have 1 directory where the retention should be 6 months.

How would that be possible?

This one would delete all files in all subdirectories which is older than 30 days if I'm correct.

```
/bin/find /root/script/* -type f -ctime +30 -exec rm {} \;
```

Bu how I can set that this directory needs different retention:

```
/root/script/owner
```

Comment: I would say: generate a list of candidates (older than 30 days), filter out the specisl directory, generate another list of candidates for the filtered folder (now older than six months) and finally remove all the elements of these two lists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can exclude the /root/script/owner from the find output using -path or -regex, combined with '!' to negate the test

```
find /root/script -type f -ctime +30 '!' -path '/root/script/owner/*' -exec rm {} \;
OR
find /root/script -type f -ctime +30 '!' -regex '/root/script/owner/.*' -exec rm {} \;
```

Then execute the custom delete on the special folder

```
find /root/script/owner -type f -ctime +180 -exec rm {} \;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can combine multiple operators so that they restrict what is included. You actually already *do* this because you have a `-type` and `-ctime`, joined with an implicit `AND`.

The one you need to add is `regex`, and you can do something like:

```
/bin/find /root/script/* -type f ! -regex '/root/script/owner/.*' -ctime +30 -exec rm {} \;
```

This should exclude files in that particular tree since the `! -regex` will be false for them. The basic idea is that only those that pass all the conditions will be subject to further operations.

In this case, any non-regular files will be excluded. Of the others, any that don't match the regex will be excluded. Of those remaining ones, we'll throw away any that don't match the 30-day requirement. Whatever's left will be actioned by the `rm`.

The remaining directory, of course, is done with the greater time:

```
/bin/find /root/script/owner -type f -ctime +186 -exec rm {} \;
```